# Continuity of the addition of two functions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

We have seen that $(f + g)$ is continuous at $x = c$ whenever both $f$ and
$g$ are. Determine whether the following statements are true or false.
Justify your answers.

(a) If $f$ is continuous at $x = c$ but $g$ is discontinuous there, then $(f +g)$
is discontinuous at $x = c$.

(b) If both $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous at $x = c$, then $(f + g)$ is discontinuous
at $x = c$.

I have no idea how to solve it.. can someone give me a hint how to do so?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your thoughts and efforts, the better we will be able to tailor answers to your needs.

Comment: For b), think at $g=-f$.

Comment: For a) Think of $(f+g) + (-f)$

Comment: i don't quite understand as I am still very new to functions. Can you explain more for both parts?

Comment: @BeHappy there is not much to explain... If $f$ discontinuous at $c$ then for $g=-f$ we have $f+g=0$ which is continuous at $c$. Same kind of reasoning for a).

Comment: how could i add a term (-f) for part a?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
a) Think at $(f+g)+(-f)$.
b) Think at $f+(-f)$.

Comment: could you explain more on both parts? I still don't get it...

Comment: @BeHappy see my comment under your question.

Comment: @BeHappy is it more clear now?

Comment: how could i add a term (-f) for part a?

Comment: well you consider the sum $\tilde f + \tilde g$ where $\tilde g = f+g$ and $\tilde f = -f$. Then you have to show that $\tilde f$ is continuous at $c$ and $\tilde g$ is not. To show that $\tilde g$ is not continuous you could use the trick I proposed in the first version of my answer (see the review history)...